# Tokenize a string in C# which delimeters contains some parts of other delimeters

Tags: c#, tokenize

I want to tokenize string using regular expressions based on some operators. But some operators inlude others as string. Such as

> **>=** , **>**, [ eg. >= contains >]

Suppose that I have a string

> (3>=4)!=(3>4)  [ operators are >= , != , >]

How to tokenize it correctly?

Comment: Depending on the complexity of the grammer, a parser generator might be better suited to your needs. I'm a big fan of GOLD Parser (http://www.goldparser.org/) I've written a compiler and a couple of interpreters using it in the past. It's a fantastic tool.

Comment: Thanks Pete. But I have some other  strange operators.And the "grammar" is a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason you have to do it with regular expressions? I would say it would be easier for you if you just used a string split function on it. If you start with the most complex operators (>=) then you don't have to worry about later splitting on >.

edit: adding example below

```
//Put operators in order of 'complexity'. Since >= contains > and =, comes before them
string[] operators = new string[] {">=", "!=", ">", "="};
string expression = "(3>=4)!=(3>4)";

foreach (string operator in operators)
{
    //Perform logic of creating expression tree here
}
```

So basically, inside the loop it's going to break down your expression. You'll need to construct your expression tree inside here based on your order of operations.

Comment: No. I do not have to use Regular expression. By starting most complex operator, you mean write most complex operator as first delimeter?

Comment: Right, I was thinking you could first split on ">=" and then split on "=" and ">". If you do it in that order you won't mess up the "complex" operators. I could provide a code sample in my answer if you want.

Comment: I do it in reqular expression with pattern which operator (>=) appear before the other one (>)